# How to display a list of items in a single line using Jinja2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, jinja2

I have a script written in Python where it fetches the on demand assets from my server and will pass as a list to an HTML using jinja2. Please see the code below.

**test.py**

```
import requests, re
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

r1 = requests.get("http://172.19.37.3:5600/cmdc/content?region=24802&currency=myr&catalogueId=24802&isPurchasable&filter=source~vod&filter=source~group&count=30&collapse=true&sort=%2btitle&pset=Group1")
r2= requests.get("http://172.19.37.3:5600/cmdc/content?region=28904&catalogueId=24802&filter=source~group&count=255")

env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'))
template = env.get_template('VOD.html')
data1 = r1.json()
data2 = r2.json()
assets1 = list()
assets2 = list()

for asset in data1['contents']:
    for media_uri in asset['media']:
        poster_uri = ""
        if media_uri['classification'] == "urn:nnds:Metro:metadata:MediaTypeCS:2007:2.1":
            poster_uri = media_uri['uri']
            a_id = (asset['id'])
            id = a_id[a_id.index('://') + 3:]
            a_id = id
            asset_id = a_id.encode('utf-8')
            asset_title = asset['title'].encode('utf-8')
            asset = [asset_id, asset_title, poster_uri]
            assets1.append(asset)
            poster_uri = poster_uri.encode('utf-8')

for asset in data2['contents']:
    for media_uri in asset['media']:
        poster_uri = ""
        if media_uri['classification'] == "urn:nnds:Metro:metadata:MediaTypeCS:2007:2.1":
            poster_uri = media_uri['uri']
            a_id = (asset['id'])
            id = a_id[a_id.index('://') + 3:]
            a_id = id
            asset_id = a_id.encode('utf-8')
            asset_title = asset['title'].encode('utf-8')
            asset = [asset_id, asset_title, poster_uri]
            assets2.append(asset)
            poster_uri = poster_uri.encode('utf-8')


templateVars = { "VOD1" : assets1, "VOD2": assets2 }

outputText = template.render( templateVars )
with open("VOD_Parsing.html", "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(outputText)
```

**VOD.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

<div id="content">
  {% for item in VOD1 %}
     <li>ID: {{ item[0] }}</li><li> Title: {{ item[1] }}</b></li>
     <img src="{{ item[2] }}" alt="dummy.jpg"> </img>
  {% endfor %}
  {% for item in VOD2 %}
     <li>ID: {{ item[0] }}</li><li> Title: {{ item[1] }}</b></li>
     <img src="{{ item[2] }}" alt="dummy.jpg"> </img>
  {% endfor %}

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The code works perfectly in passing the list of assets and printing on the html page. The problem I am facing is that all the assets and details are displayed one by one down. What I wanted is a Horizontal list of elements for the first for loop and then second horizontal line of elements for the second for loop. How can I achieve this? If I remove the li tag, then assets and details are displayed in a auto fit manner and not in a single line.

Comment: Can you show an example of what sort of output you're looking for?

Comment: @larsks... How can I show the desired output here? Is there any way to attach a screen shot?

Comment: You can include images, although there may be a reputation requirement to do that, but I was figuring you could just use text.  In particular, I'm not clear if you're asking about how to modify the generated HTML, or how to modify the presentation of the HTML as it is rendered in the browser, and an example would help clarify the nature of your question.

Comment: With limited options, i will try to explain in words here. As of now, ID, Title and the Image is displayed as a list for the first asset. Again the details are displayed for the second asset below the first one and it continues. What I really needed is List of ID, Title and Image and the next asset details of ID, Title and Image should be displayed to the right of the first one. Like that there are 25 odd details to be displayed in a single line for the first for loop. Then details should be displayed in the second line for the second for loop. I hope you can make out something from this.

Comment: @Larks... Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about HTML source being in 1 line like:

```
<li>1</li><li>2</li2>
```

then you can use `{%- -%}` notation:

```
  {%- for item in VOD1 -%}
     <li>{{ item[1] }}</li><li>{{ item[2] }}</li>
  {%- endfor -%}
  {%- for item in VOD1 -%}
     <li>{{ item[3] }}</li><li>{{ item[4] }}</li>
  {%- endfor -%}
```

If you are talking about displaying results then use 1 of this 2 - but this is not related to Jinja2:

```
li {
    display: inline;
}

li {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's a change in the HTML source. I tried your answer but I can see still it's not in a single line.

Comment: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/

You can also strip whitespace in templates by hand. If you add a minus sign (-) to the start or end of a block (e.g. a For tag), a comment, or a variable expression, the whitespaces before or after that block will be removed:

{% for item in seq -%}
    {{ item }}
{%- endfor %}

Comment: Reading you commend I think I udnerstand what you want. You really need to add example of expected output. you have 2 options. 1: remove line breaks between tags where you don't want them. like between </li> and <img>. 2(bad): place some dummy directive between tags like {%- if False -%}{%- endif -%}

Comment: I tried removing the line breaks but the problem is details are displayed in an auto fit manner. 3 assets details are displayed in the first line then 3 are in the second line like wise. I wanted all the assets in a single line.

Comment: Try:
1 - use the "-" before and after directive in both "for" blocks. Like: {%- for .... - %} {%- endfor --%} - notice the "-" on outside of directive.

2 - remove line breaks between {%endfor%} and 2nd {%for%}

Comment: And please edit your question to add expected and actual output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91498/discussion-between-roshan-r-and-alexander-trakhimenok).

Comment: Ohh ok. I tried both options but didn't work. I mentioned in words about my expected output since i don't have enough points to attach a screen shot.

Comment: Sounds like magic and I don't believe in magic.

Screenshots are bad anyway - text is cool.

Comment: Alex.. Any other solutions?